# Ngx-bootstrap's radio group wont bind to selected value on load

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ngx-bootstrap

My ngx-bootstrap radio buttons work fine and bind to selectedValue, except when the page first loads. Although selectedValue is initialized, ngModel will not bind to it when the page is first loaded.

I've tried to initialize selectedValue member in both the class and in OnInit(), hoping it was an order of operation issue, but ngModel still will not bind when the page loads.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-buttons-radio',
  templateUrl: './radio.html'
})
export class DemoButtonsRadioComponent implements OnInit {
  radioModel = 'Left';

  selectedValue: number = 0;

  familyValues: number[] = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedValue = 0;
  }
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<pre class="card card-block card-header">{{selectedValue || 'null'}}</pre>
<div class="btn-group">
       <label class="btn btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" btnRadio="0" tabindex="0" role="button">0</label>
       <label class="btn btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" btnRadio="1" tabindex="0" role="button">1</label>
       <label class="btn btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" btnRadio="2" tabindex="0" role="button">2</label>
       <label class="btn btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" btnRadio="3" tabindex="0" role="button">3</label>
       <label class="btn btn-primary" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" btnRadio="4" tabindex="0" role="button">4</label>
</div>


<div class="btn-group" *ngFor="let value of familyValues;" btnRadioGroup [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
       <label class="btn btn-success" btnRadio="{{value}}" tabindex="0" role="button">{{value}}</label>
</div>
```

The ngx-bootstrap demo works, as shown by the initial button selected. Could it be that ng-model doesn't like integers?

https://angular-je8xrf.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using attribute binding(`[btnRadio]="value"`)

```
<label 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" 
  [btnRadio]="value" 
  tabindex="0"
  role="button">
  {{value}}
</label>
```

Instead of string interpolation(`btnRadio="{{ value }}"`)

```
<label 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" 
  btnRadio="{{value}}" 
  tabindex="0"
  role="button">
  {{ value }}
</label>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-je8xrf-shdirt?file=app/radio.html) for your ref.

Comment: Weird, weird, weird and weird! Well, your solution works, but I am shocked at how horrible this stuff is! I made the assumption that Angular was way above my head and I'm the problem.

Comment: If you go back to my stackblitz and initialize it to one, the buttons don't bind but the labels do. I tried to do two sets of bindings, one static and one dynamic.  The ngx-bootstrap demo work, but now I know why they don't show any dynamic radiogroup examples!  It never worked!  

All this new tech stuff is garbage!  The emperor wears no clothes.  Anyway, thanks for the help!